# how to design movies with show times database structure

Tags: mysql, database-design

how to design movies with show times database structure

I'm building simple local cinemas guide website using Yii PHP framework.

I need Correct and improve this database, specially for showtimes

```
Cinema / done
City / done
Country / done

Movie
  id
  title
  year
  imdb_rate
  cast
  director
  summary
  views
  featured
  available_status

Genre
  id
  name
  movie_id

movie_showing
  id
  available_status
  show_time <li>20:00</li><li>22:00</li>
  movie_id  
  cinema_id

movie_video
  id
  youtube_uri
  movie_id
  trailer

movie_photo
  id
  photo_uri
  poster 0 1
  movie_id
```

Comment: I'm not sure what value is added by breaking out the video and photo information, since  they will ALWAYS pertain only to a specific movie, and not be reused

Comment: Also I would make Genre_ID a field in the movie table, not vice versa

Comment: @JNK you are right

Comment: @JNK: It might be useful if some movies have more than one photo.

Answer (score 2):

I would also suggest the following:

1. Add a movie genres table - as a movie can have one or more genres
2. Split up the movie_showing table as follows:

   - movie_showing - id, movie_id, cinema_id, details and restrictions at cinema level (this means the movie is showing at a specific cinema)
   - movie_showing_times - movie_showing_id, availability_status, showdate, showtime,  show details (prices, cinema showing, 3D or not, other offers for example half price etc)

Answer (score 0):

Why does `Genre` have a `movie_id` field? I think it would make more sense for `Movie` to have a `genre_id` field. That way you don't have to duplicate the same genre for every movie that is of that genre.

Also, `movie_showing` tells me what time the movie is at, but not on what day. I would suggest adding a `movie_date` field, unless you want to assume that it is always `sysdate` (but that would make it hard to know what days a movie showed on in the past, if you ever want to look up historical data and do reports).